# remove the #anchor-id when scrolling

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jquery http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/ to create a smooth page scroll, however each time I click a scrollable element, the anchor ID appears on the address bar.

Is there any way to prevent this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example explicitly adds the tag to the url:

```
// Set hash in URL after animation successful
location.hash = target;
```

You should be able to remove/comment this line.

Answer (score 0):

To not show hash ( a browser default behavior), return false from click handler.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  // run code
  return false;
})
```

or

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  // run code

})
```

These also prevent browser from loading a url from href, among other things they prevent

Comment: The example code is already doing this, but is adding the hash programatically.  Unless he did not use the same code, he just needs to comment out the appropriate line.

Comment: hash being set then to allow history use