# Remove anchor from url and history after jquery smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, html, url, anchor, browser-history

I have a page for which I've got smooth scrolling anchor links, using jquery 1.10 and [the code listed below](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links). The smooth scrolling works fine. After clicking the "back to top" link, an item is added to the user's history and visible in the url (as `domain.com/page#header`), which is expected.

However, because this messes up the url and breaks the functionality of the back button I'm trying to remove the anchor from the url and the browser history. I've tried several methods for removing an anchor link or a history item, but they all cause conflicts with the code for the smooth scrolling.

So my question is, does anyone know how I can remove this anchor from the url and remove the last history item, after the smooth scrolling is done?

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/CQywc/5/

**EDIT: I didn't delete this question because it was difficult for me to figure out exactly what I needed to do, even when I saw the answers to the other questions (they address a slightly different issue, and didn't explicitly resolve the added history item). So I'll leave this here for people who have the same problem I had.**

---

*Code for smooth scrolling:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
 .replace(/^\//,'')
 .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
 .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
 var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
 if (  locationPath == thisPath
 && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
 && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
   var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
   if (target) {
  var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
  $(this).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
   location.hash = target;
    });
  });
   }
 }
  });
  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
 for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
   var el = arguments[i],
    $scrollElement = $(el);
   if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
  return el;
   } else {
  $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
  var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
  $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
  if (isScrollable) {
    return el;
  }
   }
 }
 return [];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by commenting the following bit of code:

```
location.hash = target; // comment by putting two forward slashes in front of this line of code
```

Which explicitly adds the hash to the url when uncommented. Thanks to Jeff B, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509323/remove-the-anchor-id-when-scrolling). It also solves the added history item, so the back button works as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

You just add below piece of code at the end of your script, it will clear all the query string or anything else to root.

```
history.replaceState({}, '', '/');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried it, but it also clears my pagenames from the url, not just the anchor. So the url is cleared from `domain.com/page#top` to `domain.com`. But what I'm trying to accomplish is to get it to `domain.com/page`. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Simply replace with this line history.replaceState({}, '', '/page');

Comment: Yes, but that would require that page is dynamically changed to the name of the current page (I have more than one page on which I'm using this script). Or I would have to have a different version of the script for each page.. Would it not be more straightforward to clear only the anchor from the url, instead of clearing the url completely to the root address?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing to a div, you can achieve the same by this piece of code....

In **application.js**

```
function show_top(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop !=0 ){
        $ ('html, body').animate ( { scrollTop:0 } ,1000 );
    }
}
```

In view

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="show_top()">GO TO TOP</a>
```

Comment: I want to try to use anchors however, because it degrades more gracefully for those who do not have javascript enabled. But thanks for the suggestion!